# jQuery Mobile - When using checkbox arrays, attaching a label to an input with an ID containing a square bracket makes the page rendering fail

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, jquery-mobile

Can somebody explain why this HTML doesn't work for jquery mobile alpha 4? Aren't checkbox arrays supported? How do I make it work?

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Vegetables</h3>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <input type="checkbox" name="chk0[24]" id="chk0[24]" class="custom" />
                <label for="chk0[24]">Carrots</label>

                <input type="checkbox" name="chk0[75]" id="chk0[75]" class="custom" />
                <label for="chk0[75]">Eggplant</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: """ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").""" — http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name — no square brackets in id attributes.

Comment: It seems like checkbox arrays are a handy, but dodgy PHP concept. Interestingly @David quoted the HTML4 spec, which doesn't allow square brackets, but the HTML5 spec seems to allow anything other than a space as an ID: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-id-attribute.

Comment: Let me just point out that for this PHP hack (common in frameworks) you use only `name` has to contain the array notation. `id` is not sent and therefore you can put any content there. eg. chk0_24 (or skip the id at all, I bet you don't really need it)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug in jQuery Mobile, either that or they never intended you to be using square brackets inside IDs. I've never seen this array of checkboxes idea before, so it was a surprise to see it.

However, deep in the jQuery Mobile code there on line 3085 is this:

```
label = input
  .closest("form,fieldset,:jqmData(role='page')")
  .find("label")
  .filter("[for=" + input[0].id + "]"),
```

Which is passing your id into .filter, which is trying to interpret the square brackets as an attribute selector. I think jQuery Mobile should be escaping any square brackets in the ID with a double backslash, which will prevent them being interpreted by the Sizzle selector engine an attribute selector.

I think you should report this to the jQuery Mobile group at https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues

Hope this helps!

Comment: you understand the problem and know the exact line of code, therefore you are the best person to report the bug. don't be too modest with that ;)